# Laravel "in" validator

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-validation

Documentation way

```
$values = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
\Validator::make($input, ['value' => 'in:one,two,three']);
```

Can I set in options with array?
Now I use it like that, and I don't like it

```
\Validator::make($input, ['value' => 'in:' . implode(',', $values)]);
```

Comment: did you try `['value' => ['in' => $values]];` ?

Comment: yes, Method [validateEasy] does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's another way than using `implode` like you do now. Not even with a custom validation rule. The essential problem with a syntax like this

```
['value' => ['in' => $values]];
```

is that Laravel just ignores the `'in'` key and thinks `$values` are a set of validation rules.

Is there a reason why using `implode` is a problem? (other than you don't liking it)

Comment: One problem could be values containing `,`.